# Add value of DropDownList in a cookie in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I need add in a Cookie the selected value in `DropDownList`.

In the DropDownList I have:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="multiuser" runat="server" 
     AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="multiuser_SelectedIndexChanged">
     <option selected="selected" value="">-------</option>
     <option value="M40">M40</option>
     <option value="Q10">Q10</option>
     <option value="P60">P60</option>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The code of **multiuser_SelectedIndexChanged** is:

```
protected void multiuser_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cookieIdDTES = new HttpCookie("idDTES");
    cookieIdDTES.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8);
    cookieIdDTES.Value = multiuser.SelectedValue.ToString();

    Response.Write("Value of DDL: " + multiuser.SelectedValue.ToString() + "<br />");
    Response.Write("Value of Cookie : " + cookieIdDTES.Value + "<br />");

    Response.Cookies.Add(cookieIdDTES);

    Response.Write("Print request cookie : " + Request.Cookies["idDTES"].Value);
    Response.End();

}
```

If select **M40** value in `DropDownList`, the output is :

```
Value of DDL: M40
Value of Cookie : M40
Print request cookie : P60
```

If select **Q10** value in `DropDownList`, the output is :

```
Value of DDL: Q10
Value of Cookie : Q10
Print request cookie : M40
```

If select **P60** value in `DropDownList`, the output is :

```
Value of DDL: P60
Value of Cookie : P60
Print request cookie : Q10
```

The output of `Print request cookie` in all cases is always wrong ... why ?

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see that you are updating the **Response** Cookie and trying to select the value from the **Request** Cookie immediately, which will be updated on next request actually.

You can also see your result that you are always getting the last updated value from the **Request** Cookie, which is expected.

[image]

The cookie is immediately available in the HttpRequest.Cookies collection, even if the response has not been sent to the client. So that for the first time when the cookie is not available to the Request cookie collection, both value from the Response and Request cookie will be same. But what if the cookie is already in the Request. In that case, the Request cookie will not be updated until the next request.

Check the watch values, whereas the Response cookie contains value "C" and Request cookie contains "B", which is not updated with the Response cookie and contains the old value.

**NB:** I have investigated more and found that, adding in Response collection will also add new cookie in the Request collection. That means, from the second time we will get two cookies with the same name from Request collection.
For example, Request.Cookies["Selection1"] can be found in index 4 and 5, where index 4 contains the old value and the 5 contains the newest value. But if we try to retrieve the value with the name, it will return the first one that means the previous one.

Comment: After you add a cookie by using the HttpResponse.Cookies collection, the cookie is immediately available in the HttpRequest.Cookies collection, even if the response has not been sent to the client. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cookies.aspx

Comment: @GraDea: Good point. Thanks for bringing this to my attention. Its not how I would expect it to work, I have to admit. :)

Comment: @GraDea: Thanks for your comments. Yes the cookie is immediately available in the HttpRequest.Cookies collection, even if the response has not been sent to the client. So that for the first time when the cookie is not available to the Request cookie collection, both value from the Response and Request cookie will be same. 
**But what if the cookie is already in the Request. In that case, the Request cookie will not be updated until the next request.** 

I think you will understand what I meant. :)

Comment: @Chris: You can also check this and I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1):

After you add a cookie by using the HttpResponse.Cookies collection, the cookie is immediately copy to the HttpRequest.Cookies collection.

And collection Request.Cookies contains two cookies with name idDTES.

You can check this

```
foreach (var item in Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
{
    Response.Write("ALL request cookie : " + item + "<br />");
}
```

You can remove old cookie from request before adding

```
Request.Cookies.Remove("idDTES");
Response.Cookies.Add(cookieIdDTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void multiuser_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
cookieIdDTES = new HttpCookie("idDTES");
cookieIdDTES.Expires = DateTime.Now;
cookieIdDTES.Value = multiuser.SelectedValue.ToString();

Response.Write("Value of DDL: " + multiuser.SelectedValue.ToString() + "<br />");
Response.Write("Value of Cookie : " + cookieIdDTES.Value + "<br />");

Response.Cookies.Add(cookieIdDTES);

Response.Write("Print request cookie : " + Request.Cookies["idDTES"].Value);
Response.End();

}
```

Comment: thank you, but I have this error `System.NullReferenceException: object reference not set to an instance of an object` in the line `Response.Write("Print request cookie : " + Request.Cookies["Name"].Value);`

Comment: Response.Write("Print request cookie : " + cookieIdDTES["Name"]) try this way

Comment: The problem lies with the expiration `cookieIdDTES.Expires` it has been set after 8 hours of current time. So multiple cookie will be created with same name `idDTES`. On retrieve it will get according to `fifo` expiration should be current time.

Comment: @KaushikMaheta The output is empty with `Response.Write("Print request cookie : " + cookieIdDTES["Name"]) `

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal thank you, I don't understand your suggestion I am sorry.

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq, cookieIdDTES.Expires = DateTime.Now; replace this line and also see my updated answer.

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq:  `cookieIdDTES.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8);` should be `cookieIdDTES.Expires = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal But in this mode I can't use the value of cookies in other webpages ... because the cookie expire immediatly ... my problem is the managing users Multiprofile ....

Comment: [Multiple values with single cookie](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/8809/get-and-set-multiple-values-in-a-single-cookie-in-Asp-Net.aspx) Try this out.

Comment: Code only answers aren't very helpful. You should explain what you are doing and why.